# Measure cache misses in JVM

Tags: java, jvm, jprofiler

Is it possible to measure cache misses in a running JVM?

Even better, is there a way to get these metrics in JProfiler? Or any other profiler?

I have explored JProfiler options and haven't seen an inspection for this.

Comment: cache misses in what cache?

Comment: You could try Oracle Solaris Studio which also runs on Linux (but not windows)

Comment: looking for misses in L2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On linux you can use [perf-map-agent](https://github.com/jrudolph/perf-map-agent) which provides java integration for [perf-tools](https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page).

[async-profiler](https://github.com/jvm-profiling-tools/async-profiler) is another tool supporting perf events.

Comment: I guess it's not possible to use async-profiler for this on Mac OS X yet: https://github.com/jvm-profiling-tools/async-profiler/issues/182

Answer (score -1):

No, this is beyond the scope of a Java profiler.